# Crowdstrike Sensors - Do they need inbound, as well as outbound access?

Tags: vulnerability

As per the title, I'm looking for insight on the crowdstrike sensor. Does anyone know if, on top of the outbound pt:443 access to the domains it requires, whether it also requires inbound connectivity?

Comment: This appears to be a vendor question since it is about the function of a product.